# How to get an error of query to athena via boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

Does boto3 have any method which allows one to get the text of the error if the query failed? `get_query_execution` returns a status of the query only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the error message from `'StateChangeReason'` field of your `response['Status']`.

As per [`get_query_execution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution) documentation:

> StateChangeReason (string) --
> Further detail about the status of the query.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('athena')

failed_query_id = '08adbf00-5f14-4d54-9311-fd55e2024781'
response = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=failed_query_id)
print(response['Status']['StateChangeReason'])
```